# Why does not `\shortintertext` command work if we load `nccmath` after `mathtools`?

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, mathtools, nccmath

If you load `nccmath` after `mathtools` and use `\shortintertext`, you will get an error message "Package amsmath Error: Invalid use of `\shortintertext`". If you load `nccmath` before `mathtools`, the error message disappears.

Is there any overlap between the two packages functionalities? Do they overlap when it comes to modifying the internal commands of the standard LaTeX?

```
\documentclass[]{book}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    (A + B \thinspace C) \thinspace x + C \thinspace y &= 0,
    \\
    \shortintertext{Short Intertext}
    E \thinspace x + (F + G) \thinspace y &= 23.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\intertext` and `\shortintertext` commands are only valid in certain contexts; `nccmath` modifies the meaning of `\intertext@` (which is the internal command defined by `amsmath` and used also by `mathtools`) and eventually this conflicts with the redefinitions done by `mathtools`.

Solution: load `nccmath` before `mathtools`. This will remove the redefinition of `\intertext` done by `nccmath`, but it's not needed because you can use `\shortintertext` with similar features.

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    (A + B C) x + C y &= 0,
    \\
    \shortintertext{Short Intertext}
    E x + (F + G) y &= 23.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I removed all the `\thinspace` commands which are not needed and wrong anyhow: for a thin space in math mode you should use `\,`. But, really, it is not needed in those places.

[image]

Comment: `\thinspace` is more readable in my LaTeX editor. It is shown in light olive green. `\,` has the same color of the rest of the math in my editor. I add these small spaces to enhance to overall appearance and readability of the document (at least this is how I feel about it)

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh It's wrong anyhow, because it inserts a (text) kern instead of a math space.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's some overlap in this respect, because  `nccmath` adds an optionnal argument to the standard `\intertext` to specify the vertical spacing inserted above and below \intertext (p.2 of the documentation).